# Stack - symbol balance checker

Tags: c++

I need help just outlining this code for c++. Any tips?

Implement a symbol balance checker function for the Pascal programming language.  Pascal allows for the following pairs: {}, (), [], begin end .  All programs will begin with the word "begin" and end  with the word "end".  Your function should receive an ifstream object which is already open and will return true, all of the symbols match, or false, they do not.  You do not have to worry about comments in the program but you do have to avoid other parts of the program's code such as assignment statements (x=y) and other expressions.

Comment: So keep a counter for each symbol group.  If all zero at the end, good.  Of course, this fails for true parsing because `{(})` is illegal - should be easy to check for that though with counts. :)

Comment: Basically, only legal to subtract the last symbol added fixes my case.  In real life, it forms a stack and when a symbol is found, it won't pop that symbol unless it matches the last push.  That should be enough of a hint.